# I am retrieving a data form Ms.Access file but it show me file name How to fix it?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to retrieve the data from MS.Access through list but when run the application it show me all entries but just file name like Student.StudentInformation I don't know why and then When i select the first entry i show me  right data in textBox?
I query is:

```
public ICollection<StudentInformation> GetStudents()
   {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Students";

       ObservableCollection<StudentInformation> students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
       try
       {
           con.Open();
           OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               Student aStudent = new Student(Convert.ToInt32(reader["StudentID"]),
                                               reader["StudentName"].ToString(),
                                               reader["StudentEmail"].ToString());

               students.Add(aStudent);
           }
           reader.Close();
           return students;
       }
       finally
       {
           con.Close();
       }
   }
```

In Student Information Class i did get set and made two constructor.One is default constructor and second pass the values.

and I am showing in list box:

```
private ICollection<StudentInformation> students;
 private void BtnGetStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        students = StudentDb.GetStudents();
        Studentlst.ItemsSource = students;
    }
```

It show me list like Student.StudentInformation
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a presentation problem. You should explain the WPF (you are using WPF, right?) how to display a `StudentInformation`.

As a simple workaround, you can overload the function `ToString()` for `StudentInformation`, but the better solution would be writing a `DataTemplate` for it. (Do you know how to do it?)

A note aside: accessing the database in the UI thread is not a very good idea, this would block your UI for the duration of the query.

Comment: Thanks alot i tried to do Overload function and it works.Thank you so much.